# View on top of all screens of app in android

Tags: android

I have a requirement in which I need to show a UI with text view on top of screen of app. If we navigate to other screen while this UI is displayed , it should show on that screen as well.UI will be shown for fixed duration but I don't know how can I achieve this without injecting view in all activities.

is there any other good way to do this?

Comment: Where is the UI?

Comment: You will have to use Fragments and Dialog. Move from one fragment to another while the Overlay UI("View on top of all screen") is displayed.